# Dynamically creating objects in C

Tags: c, object, struct, global, declaration

Hello, guys!

I'm familiar with JavaScript and PHP, but new to C. 
I am trying to play around with graphics in C and craete colision algorithm. Now, I need to create objects dynamically, just like in more advanced languages. For example, I need to create a polygon via my own function and make it an object that would be visible to the whole script. I assume, a struct would be needed.

As far as I know, everything declared in a function stays in a function. How can I dynamically declare global structs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is a fairly static language. By static I mean, you can create memory during run-time, but you will need pointers to address that memory declared at compile time. That is if you are going to need memory during run-time and do not want to declare it during compile time, you will need to use malloc and free (when you've finished with the memory).

To create a global structure whose memory you would create at run time, you would minimally need a pointer to a structure at compile time. If you need several of those structures, you could create several structures' worth of memory, but traversing the structures would be tedious without having an array of those structures. You would need that array of pointers to structures at compile time. There are some ways to make this more dynamic, but in decade or so I used C and C++, we never ran into those other ways, including in device drivers.

When you say create objects in C, you really have no objects you can create other than those created by a function call to a library or creating memory from the heap, and then interpreting that memory by overlapping structure or array pointers over it.

Functions can alter parameters if those parameters are passed in by reference (a pointer to the parameter), and functions can return nothing or return a single atom of data, a char, integer, smallint, or pointer.

Answer (score 2):

a. function can return value.

b. you can use global variables.

c (and probably the most useful). dynamically allocate memory (using `malloc`,etc) and return pointer to it. (And remember to free it after using)

Comment: I guess you really meant "you **shall never** use global variables"

Comment: Only if you know what you're doing. I'd venture to guess the OP doesn't.

Comment: Let him learn... We all wrote some bad programs, got stack overflow, googled that phrase, and began to learn...

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a struct or a more complex abstract data type (ADT) to hold your dynamically created variables. Once you have this, you can create the any object you want via malloc(), and store it in there.

As I mentioned earlier, it would be highly recommended to have a look at the ADTs and learn how to work with them. This will allow you to create any complex data structure like queues or linked lists in order to work a little more OOP oriented.

Answer (score 2):

declare global pointers(array of pointers) of the same type as the structure. Use the functions like malloc etc. to dynamically allocate memory and assign it to the pointers.